# "Merging" a stream of streams to produce a stream of the latest values of each

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` where each inner `IObservable<T>` is a stream of values followed by an eventual `OnCompleted` event.

I would like to transform this into an `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>`, a stream consisting of the latest value from any inner stream that is not completed. It should produce a new `IEnumerable<T>` whenever a new value is produced from one of the inner streams (or an inner stream expires)

It is most easily shown with a marble diagram (which I hope is comprehensive enough):

```
input ---.----.---.----------------
         |    |   '-f-----g-|      
         |    'd------e---------|
         'a--b----c-----|          

result ---a--b-b--c-c-c-e-e-e---[]-
               d  d d e f g        
                    f f
```

(`[]` is an empty `IEnumerable<T>` and `-|` represents the OnCompleted)

You can see that it slightly resembles a `CombineLatest` operation.
I have been playing around with `Join` and `GroupJoin` to no avail but I feel that that is almost certainly the right direction to be heading in.

I would like to use as little state as possible in this operator.

### Update

I have updated this question to include not just single-valued sequences - the resultant `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>` should include only the latest value from each sequence - if a sequence has not produced a value, it should not be included.

Comment: Obviously you will need some state here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen could you explain why?

Comment: It is impossible to do without state because by definition the operator needs to track every inner sequences until it completes.

Comment: The solution you had yesterday would work with some minor tweaks.  If you can repost it, I'll show you the tweaks.

Comment: @Brandon - I have undeleted the solution that I believe you meant. Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version based your solution yesterday, tweaked for the new requirements.  The basic idea is to just put a reference into your perishable collection, and then update the value of the reference as the inner sequence produces new values.

I also modified to properly track the inner subscriptions and unsubscribe if the outer observable is unsubscribed.

Also modified to tear it all down if any of the streams produce an error.

Finally, I fixed some race conditions that could violate Rx Guidelines.  If your inner observables are firing concurrently from different threads, you could wind up call `obs.OnNext` concurrently which is a big no-no.  So I've gated each inner observable using the same lock to prevent that (see the `Synchronize` call).  Note that because of this, you could probably get away with using a regular double linked list instead of the `PerishableCollection` because now all of the code using the collection is within a lock so you don't need the threading guarantees of the `PerishableCollection`.

```
// Acts as a reference to the current value stored in the list
private class BoxedValue<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public BoxedValue(T initialValue) { Value = initialValue; }
}

public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> MergeLatest<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<T>>(obs =>
    {
        var collection = new PerishableCollection<BoxedValue<T>>();
        var outerSubscription = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
        var subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable(outerSubscription);
        var innerLock = new object();

        outerSubscription.Disposable = source.Subscribe(duration =>
        {
            BoxedValue<T> value = null;
            var lifetime = new DisposableLifetime(); // essentially a CancellationToken
            var subscription = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();

            subscriptions.Add(subscription);
            subscription.Disposable = duration.Synchronize(innerLock)
                .Subscribe(
                    x =>
                    {
                        if (value == null)
                        {
                            value = new BoxedValue<T>(x);
                            collection.Add(value, lifetime.Lifetime);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            value.Value = x;
                        }
                        obs.OnNext(collection.CurrentItems().Select(p => p.Value.Value));
                    },
                    obs.OnError, // handle an error in the stream.
                    () => // on complete
                    {
                        if (value != null)
                        {
                            lifetime.Dispose(); // removes the item
                            obs.OnNext(collection.CurrentItems().Select(p => p.Value.Value));
                            subscriptions.Remove(subscription); // remove this subscription
                        }
                    }
            );
        });

        return subscriptions;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it is easy to follow, although I did wonder if it was possible to do in an immutable fashion. And another +1 if I could for the added thread safety!

Comment: Minor point: the .NET Framework provides `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StrongBox` which is effectively the same as your `BoxedValue`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for one-item streams but unfortunately accumulates every item in an inner stream until it finishes.

```
public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> MergeLatest<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<T>>(obs =>
    {
        var collection = new PerishableCollection<T>();
        return source.Subscribe(duration =>
        {
            var lifetime = new DisposableLifetime(); // essentially a CancellationToken
            duration
                .Subscribe(
                    x => // on initial item
                    {
                        collection.Add(x, lifetime.Lifetime);
                        obs.OnNext(collection.CurrentItems().Select(p => p.Value));
                    },
                    () => // on complete
                    {
                        lifetime.Dispose(); // removes the item
                        obs.OnNext(collection.CurrentItems().Select(p => p.Value));
                    }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another solution given by Dave Sexton](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbfc31d0-d337-41d9-946c-0134f9474caa/how-can-i-merge-an-ioiot-to-produce-an-ioienumt-containing-only-the-most-recent-values-of), creator of [Rxx](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) - it uses [Rxx.CombineLatest](http://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1.3/Source/Rxx/System/Reactive/Linq/Observable2%20-%20CombineLatest.cs) which appears to be quite similar in its implementation to Brandon's solution:

```
public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> CombineLatestEagerly<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> source)
{
  return source
    // Reify completion to force an additional combination:
    .Select(o => o.Select(v => new { Value = v, HasValue = true })
                  .Concat(Observable.Return(new { Value = default(T), HasValue = false })))
    // Merge a completed observable to force combination with the first real inner observable:
    .Merge(Observable.Return(Observable.Return(new { Value = default(T), HasValue = false })))
    .CombineLatest()
    // Filter out completion notifications:
    .Select(l => l.Where(v => v.HasValue).Select(v => v.Value));
}
```

Comment: Yeah I meant to mention that Rxx had a `CombineLatest` overload that almost did what you wanted.  Sorry about that.  Since I use Rxx in my projects, if I had to solve this problem, this is the solution I'd use.  The code is smaller than mine and more understandable than Matthew's.

Comment: I'd be a little concerned that the last value sticks around in the collection (even if it's not seen) once an inner stream completes. This means that over time, with enough streams, the number of 'leftover' items would grow quite large. With your solution the boxed value is removed from the collection as soon as the stream is complete.

Comment: ah yeah that is an issue I didn't realize it had.